# Button flip animation out of frame on the uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uibutton

**Update, SOLVED**

Sorry for my english, but i will do my best.

I have a problem with a button flip animation.

I want the UIButtons to fill the UIView. But how do i do that?

Here is my problem.
I have two UIButtons in a UIView.
When i press the first button it will flip correctly but when i press the second button that it have flipped to the UIView is still the same size but the UIButton image is changing size to the original size of the image and it also move the image to the upper left corner off the view controller. The same thing will repeat every time it flip.

Here is the flip animation code.

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressedFlip {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

if (flipState == 0) {
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:buttonContainer cache:YES];

    [self.btn1 removeFromSuperview];
    [buttonContainer addSubview:btn2];
    flipState = 1;
}

else {
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:buttonContainer cache:YES];

    [self.btn2 removeFromSuperview];
    [buttonContainer addSubview:btn1];
    flipState = 0;
}

[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Have a nice day and thanks for any help!

**I solved the problem like this**

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressedFlip {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

if (flipState == 0) {

    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:buttonContainer cache:YES];
    [self.buttonContainer bringSubviewToFront:btn2];
    flipState = 1;

}

else {

    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:buttonContainer cache:YES];
    [self.buttonContainer bringSubviewToFront:btn1];
    flipState = 0;

}

[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved the problem**

See my update code.